# React-Apollo error: "...only supports a query, subscription, or a mutation per HOC"

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-mutation

I am trying to create two separate mutations in this format:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const MUTATION = gql`
  mutation setItem($item:String!) {
    setItem(item:$item)
  },
  mutation setAnotherItem($setAnotherItem:Bool) {
    setAnotherItem(setAnotherItem:$setAnotherItem)
  }
`;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Invariant Violation: react-apollo only supports a query, subscription, or a mutation per HOC. [object Object] had 0 queries, 0 subscriptions and 2 mutations. You can use 'compose' to join multiple operation types to a component
```

What is the proper way to structure this so that both mutations are usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type just once `mutation` and nest inside the (mutation) fields:

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const MUTATION = gql`
  mutation MyMutation ($item: String, $setAnotherItem: Book) {
    setItem(item: $item) { ...}
    setAnotherItem(setAnotherItem: $setAnotherItem) {...}
  }
`;
```

Comment: This is also applicable in composing multiple queries, subscriptions operations in react-apollo. Quite a brilliant.